# Background Js undefined Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome

```
console.log(chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:"script2",message:"hello!"}));
```

**Mean While I am trying to send the message from background script to content script which is not working**

[image: this is the picture that throws me error for every code I use throws me "undefined" message]

Answer (score 0):

It may mean that it was sent successfully.

I recommend looking at **Network**, then clicking on the request *GET* or *POST* and finally looking at the response.

Comment: No, the response is nothing actually. I have tried different ways to send messages from background script to content script but it fails every time.
I used the session cookie storage but didn't work.